# Change boolean value of some data where date == DateTime.Today

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm working on an application with mvc5 and want that when I load a page, it will check if datetime of data equals `DateTime.Today` in table, and if so, that it will then set a boolean value to true.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Detail v = db.Details.Single(emp => emp.DateExpired.Value.Equals( DateTime.Today));
    v.Expire = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

It gives me this error
[image: Error screenshot]

because there was more than one for which this date equals `DateTime.Today`,

What can be done to take this possibility into account?

Comment: Use a where clause instead of single. Then use foreach on the returned enumerable of detail objects. Then save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    foreach (var r in db.Details.Where(emp => emp.DateExpired.HasValue && emp.DateExpired.Value == DateTime.Today))
    {
        r.Expire = true;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Single()` works where it expects only one result to be returned and will throw an error when it finds a match.  From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb155325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

For your case you should use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`
`FirstOrDefault` will return a null when no match is found.

Edit : 
If you want to apply the logic on all matches you should use `Where()`

Comment: OP is asking _how apply this on **more** data which this date equals DateTime.Today_ so a `.Where()` is required

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I guess glossed over that part